# Software implementation sought: Bookmarks in web browsers, like Chrome: making any bookmark tree node the root of a tree with logical arrangement

Tags: web-browser, chrome, nlp, artificial-intelligence, browser-extension

I am looking for some code, perhaps a chrome plugin, that would allow you to do research in the areas of bookmark organization and bookmark organization design.

In Android, one can switch and plug in one's favorite keyboard.

There is no reason why the same management, should not be applicable, to, Chrome, browser, bookmark, manager.

....

Important. Here is wha I, am looking for:

Bookmarks are currently arranged in browsers, as tree lists.

Several, other, ⛴️ API, widgets, and lists, present, trees, and tree views.

What can be realized, is that, if we choose a node in a tree, we can make the node the root of the tree by redrawing the tree, specified, with the given, root node (other tree node), as the new root node.

Indeed, we can call a procedure called makeRootNode() on any node of a tree.

However, this is not what I am looking for.

I am looking at making the bookmark (a node in the bookmark tree), a root node, of a tree, considering the whole graph (larger, with more arrow edges between bookmarks, in the complete bookmark graph (the graph that links, bookmarks (containing the bookmark, tree)), of bookmarks.

I want AI with NLP (natural language processing), and NLP analysis, to go though the bookmarks, and, rearrange, a new tree, based on NLP logic.

The first step is going though the bookmarks though a tree iterator and selecting those that belong, in some set way (you can specify a threshold, of acceptance, of the bookmark content, as a user variable, in the settings), ... that belong to the same context.

The remaining details are found below.

....

The code would not consider the whole set of bookmarks. It would draw a complete graph on the relevant nodes (those, that, via AI, were deemed relevant). It would then use AI to compete, the drawing, of a spanning tree, based on the selected node within the complete graph.

It would then place all nodes that were not deemed relevant, in a tree, found below.

The, user, can further indirect these, in case, they may want, to see, what went right, and, what, night, have gone winning into the wrong place.

...

So, where can I find such software?

Has this been implemented anywhere?

When, will it, or can it, be implemented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How would the UI for this look like?
Sounds like you are looking for something like [exclusive tagging](https://bookmarkmanager.com/tagging). You can find an example of this implemented in a bookmark manager [here](https://bookmarkmanager.com/demo).

Comment: Hi Simon, link only answers are discouraged and the intention is to give a review on your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I would export my bookmarks as HTML, load the exported file into an AI system that supports uploading of files, and that understands the format ([ChatGPT Pro](https://chat.openai.com/) . At this time non-free GPT-4 with Code Interpreter Plugin comes to mind. Start a conversation with it to reorganize  your bookmark list, re-clustering and reclassifying  subtopics.

Takes some time to learn patterns of interactions, prompting the AI system and to get it to produce *complete* output . However I think reorganizing your bookmark list is not something you do often. Therefore the one-off interaction (even in multiple attempts ) might be a feasible approach.

Otherwise read this paper from Dec 2023 [Large Language Models on Graphs: A Comprehensive Survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.02783) - Figure 2 might contain some pointers to academic projects and little-known software.